# Help me translate this encrypted message

Tags: cipher

The message is: TFNBdUxpNHVJQzR1SUM0dUxpQXZJQzR1SUM0dUxpQXZJQzR0SUM4Z0xpMHRMU0F0TFMwZ0xpNHRJQzR0TGlBdExpQXVMU0F1TFM0dUlDNHRMaTB1TFNBdklDOGdMaT B0TFMwZ0xpMHVMUzR0SUM4Z0x5QXVMaUF2SUM0dUxpNGdMaTBnTFNBdUlDOGdMUzBnTFM0dExTQXZJQzB1TGlBdUxTQXRMaTRnTGkwdUxTNHRJQzhnTGk0Z0xpMHRMUzB1SUM0dUxpMGdMaUF2SUMwdUxpNGdMaUF1SUMwdUlDOG dMU0F1TGk0dUlDNHVJQzB1SUMwdUxTQXVMaUF0TGlBdExTNGdMeUF1TFNBdExp NHVJQzB0TFNBdUxpMGdMU0F2SUM0dUxpNGdMaTRnTFMwZ0x5QXVMU0F2SUM0dExpNGdMUzB0SUMwZ0x5 QXVMUzR1SUM0dElDMGdMaUF1TFM0dUlDMHVMUzBnTGkwdUxTNHRJQzhnTGk0Z0xpMHRMUzB1SUMwdElDOGdMUzB0SUMwdUlDOGdMaTBnTHlBdExpNHVJQz R1TFNBdUxpNGdMeUF0SUMwdExTQXZJQzR1TFM0Z0xpNHRJQzB1TFM0Z0xTNHRJQzR1SUMwdUlDMHRMaUF2SUMwdElDNHRJQzB1SUM4Z0xTNHRMaUF1TGk0dUlDNGdMaTR1SU MwZ0x5QXVMaTR1SUM0dElDNHVJQzR0TGlBdExTNHVMUzBnTHlBdElDMHRMU0 F2SUM0dUxpQXVJQzRnTHlBdUlDNHRMaTRnTGk0Z0x5QXVMUzBnTGk0dUxpQXVMaUF1TFM0dUlDNGdMeUF1TFMwZ0xpMHVJQzR1SUMwZ0xpNGdMUzRnTFMwdUlDOGdMU0F1TGk0dUlDNHVJQzR1TGlBdklDNHVMaUF0TFMwZ0x5QXVMaUF1TFMwdExTNGdMUzBnTHlBdEx pQXRMUzBnTFNBdklDMHRMaUF0TFMwZ0xTNGdMUzRnTGkwZ0x5QXVMaTRnT GkwZ0xTNHRMU0F2SUM0dElDOGdMaTB1TGlBdExTMGdMU0F1TFM0dExpMGdMeUF1TGkwZ0xTMHVJQzR1TGk0Z0xpMHVMUzR0

I found this message in some kind of weird blog, and I have been trying to decipher it.
It is next to a binary message and a morse message, so I ran it through a lot of online decoders, but none were right.

There are no hints, but I noticed the letters "xp" keep repeating every 10 or less characters, maybe it is a blank space? Also, the letters "TFNBd", "MaT" and "NHR" are repeatead a bunch of times each.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Before we proceed, could you add more info regarding the source of the puzzle? The puzzle without proper attribution will generally be closed :)

Comment: *"It is next to a binary message and a Morse message"* - So you had the Rosetta stone but didn't show it to us?

Comment: The answer seem to contain rot13(cebsnavgl). Please give credits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's multiple layers of encoding here, but thankfully, none of them are too hard to figure out.

Outermost layer:

> Base64. Result of decoding:
>
> > LSAuLi4uIC4uIC4uLiAvIC4uIC4uLiAvIC4tIC8gLi0tLSAtLS0gLi4tIC4tLiAtLiAuLSAuLS4uIC4tLi0uLSAvIC8gLi0tLS0gLi0uLS4tIC8gLyAuLiAvIC4uLi4gLi0gLSAuIC8gLS0gLS4tLSAvIC0uLiAuLSAtLi4gLi0uLS4tIC8gLi4gLi0tLS0uIC4uLi0gLiAvIC0uLi4gLiAuIC0uIC8gLSAuLi4uIC4uIC0uIC0uLSAuLiAtLiAtLS4gLyAuLSAtLi4uIC0tLSAuLi0gLSAvIC4uLi4gLi4gLS0gLyAuLSAvIC4tLi4gLS0tIC0gLyAuLS4uIC4tIC0gLiAuLS4uIC0uLS0gLi0uLS4tIC8gLi4gLi0tLS0uIC0tIC8gLS0tIC0uIC8gLi0gLyAtLi4uIC4uLSAuLi4gLyAtIC0tLSAvIC4uLS4gLi4tIC0uLS4gLS4tIC4uIC0uIC0tLiAvIC0tIC4tIC0uIC8gLS4tLiAuLi4uIC4gLi4uIC0gLyAuLi4uIC4tIC4uIC4tLiAtLS4uLS0gLyAtIC0tLSAvIC4uLiAuIC4gLyAuIC4tLi4gLi4gLyAuLS0gLi4uLiAuLiAuLS4uIC4gLyAuLS0gLi0uIC4uIC0gLi4gLS4gLS0uIC8gLSAuLi4uIC4uIC4uLiAvIC4uLiAtLS0gLyAuLiAuLS0tLS4gLS0gLyAtLiAtLS0gLSAvIC0tLiAtLS0gLS4gLS4gLi0gLyAuLi4gLi0gLS4tLSAvIC4tIC8gLi0uLiAtLS0gLSAuLS4tLi0gLyAuLi0gLS0uIC4uLi4gLi0uLS4t

Middle layer:

> Base64 (again). Result of decoding:
>
> > - .... .. ... / .. ... / .- / .--- --- ..- .-. -. .- .-.. .-.-.- / / .---- .-.-.- / / .. / .... .- - . / -- -.-- / -.. .- -.. .-.-.- / .. .----. ...- . / -... . . -. / - .... .. -. -.- .. -. --. / .- -... --- ..- - / .... .. -- / .- / .-.. --- - / .-.. .- - . .-.. -.-- .-.-.- / .. .----. -- / --- -. / .- / -... ..- ... / - --- / ..-. ..- -.-. -.- .. -. --. / -- .- -. / -.-. .... . ... - / .... .- .. .-. --..-- / - --- / ... . . / . .-.. .. / .-- .... .. .-.. . / .-- .-. .. - .. -. --. / - .... .. ... / ... --- / .. .----. -- / -. --- - / --. --- -. -. .- / ... .- -.-- / .- / .-.. --- - .-.-.- / ..- --. .... .-.-.-

Innermost layer:

> Morse code. Result of decoding:
>
> > THIS IS A JOURNAL. 1. I HATE MY DAD. I'VE BEEN THINKING ABOUT HIM A LOT LATELY. I'M ON A BUS TO FUCKING MAN CHEST HAIR, TO SEE ELI WHILE WRITING THIS SO I'M NOT GONNA SAY A LOT. UGH.

Comment: Not exactly the best journal entry.